# programmatically refreshing a datagrid in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp.net webpage that does a bunch of (slow, hence the problem) calculations and dumps them all into a datagrid in a webpage.  I would like to be able to have the page show partial results.

I have figured out how to re-update the grid every time a row is done, but the page still doesn't display the results until all the calculations are complete.  Does anyone know a call from asp.net that can tell the page to refresh itself?

p.s. the update function I am currently using is as follows:

```
    private void updateDisplay(DataTable outputTable)
    {
        if (outputTable.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Clear();

            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br>"));
            GridView myView = new GridView();
            myView.DataSource = outputTable;
            myView.DataBind();
            myView.Visible = true;

            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(myView);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always use something like the [Ajax Timer](http://www.asp.net/ajax/videos/how-do-i-use-the-aspnet-ajax-timer-control) along with some [efficient paging](http://dotnetblogger.com/post/2010/03/07/RadGrid-with-Custom-Paging-Sorting-Filtering.aspx) (only pulling a small amount of data instead of everything).

This way you do a short select statement for say 10 records on an interval of every 3 seconds, and you do it outside of the process thread.

If you'd rather keep it the way you have it with updating the grid every time a row is added, then that's fine too, just make sure you start your **big heavy, lifting** process in a separate [BackgroundWorker](http://www.dotneat.net/2009/02/10/BackgroundworkerExample.aspx). I would also still implement the more efficient paging in order to keep your select statements small and streamlined.

Comment: How does moving the heavy lifting to a background worker thread actually help anything?

Comment: it makes it so that the application can still perform it's tasks and give the user a nice user experience without having to wait for a large task to complete.  Example: I had to have an app insert roughly 10,000 records through a CSV upload ... I didn't want the user to wait for the insert (only the actual upload).. so I backgrounded the DB insert function so they could go on with what they needed to do without waiting for the insert to complete.